# I want to show size attributs in product page dynamically same as below screnshot how can i do that

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I want to show sizes attribute like shown in the image in my custom theme.

[image: Refer Image Here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solve this by adding code in my **custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.main">
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.demo" template="product/view/attr.phtml" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSizesAvailable</argument>
            <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">Sizes_Available</argument>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">Sizes_Available</argument>
            <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Sizes Available</argument>
            <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="Sizes_Available"</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
    <move element="product.info.demo" destination="product.info.main" after="product.info.price" />
</referenceBlock>
```

**And in custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attr.phtml**

```
<?php
   $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
   $_product = $block->getProduct();
   $_code = $block->getAtCode();
   $_className = $block->getCssClass();
   $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
   $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
   $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();
   if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
   $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
}
  $_attributeValue =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>
 <?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>
 <div>
    <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo  $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>>
    <p><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></p>
   </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```